# Value Binding On Select With Static Options

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

is it possible use the value binding on a select that contains static options like this?

```
<select data-bind="value: optionValue">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option> 
</select>
```

Actually the bind is writing the value, if I select an option the value will change, but I am not able to read it when the select is initialized. When the page is loaded the first option is always setted.

Comment: You may have something else going on.  Maybe you can reproduce based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KzQAp/

Comment: I am using it in dynamic context and if I rebind the viewmodel is fine.

Comment: It would be helpful to reproduce in a jsFiddle, if you can.

Comment: This problem happen just some times. Probably because there is a delay in the binding.